# Find a cut of a graph that minimizes the ratio between the edge weights of the cut and the edge weights inside one subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms

Given an edge-weighted undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ (can assume the weights are non-negative) and a source node $v_s\in V$, a cut is a partition of $G$'s vertices into two complementary sets $S$ and $T$. We always let $v_s\in S$, define $W_{c}$ be the cut value, i.e. the sum of weights of the edges that connect one vertex in $S$ and one vertex in $T$, and define $W_{s}$ be the value of $S$: the sum of weights of the edges that connect two vertices within $S$. The problem is to find a cut that minimizes $W_{c}/W_{s}$.

Does this problem have a polynomial solution (w.r.t the number of vertices)?

Thanks!